# Very Odd issue with nested for loops in C, data is inconsistent

Tags: c, for-loop, random, nested, infinite-loop

I've exhausted all the debugging I know here and decided to ask for help here. This is for a school assignment meant to simulate paging for a FIFO algorithm for table sizes 3 and 4, in an attempt to monitor whether we can observe Beladys anomaly occurring.

Basically I have the following code in my main:

```
int i;
srand(time(NULL));
int faults[2], threeTable[3], fourTable[4];
int p;
    int beladyOccured = 0;
    int beladyNot = 0;
    count = 20;
    for(p = 0; p < 1000; p++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand() % 5;
        }
        initializeTables(threeTable, 3);
        faults[0] = fifo(threeTable, 3);
        initializeTables(fourTable, 4);
        faults[1] = fifo(fourTable, 4);
        if (detectBelady(faults[1], faults[0]) == 1)
        {
            beladyOccured++;
            printf("Belady's Anomaly occured, p is %d, i is %d, number of faults for three is %d, number of faults for four is %d, belady occurances is %d, and non-occurances is %d", p, i, faults[0], faults[4], beladyOccured, beladyNot);
        }
        else
        {
            beladyNot++;
            printf("Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is %d, i is %d, number of faults for three is %d, number of faults for four is %d, belady occurances is %d, and non-occurances is %d \n", p, i, faults[0], faults[4], beladyOccured, beladyNot);

        }
    }

    printf("Using frame sizes 3 and 4, beladys algorithm occured %d times and did not occur %d times \n", beladyOccured, beladyNot);
return 0;
```

I have the following global declarations:

```
int arr[101], count;
```

My output looks something like this though:

```
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 3, i is 0, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 12
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 4, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 13
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 3, i is 0, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 14
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 0, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 15
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 3, number of faults for three is 12, number of faults for four is 4, belady occurances is 4, and non-occurances is 4
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 4, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 4, belady occurances is 4, and non-occurances is 5
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 5, i is 1, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 4, belady occurances is 4, and non-occurances is 6
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 6, i is 4, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 4, belady occurances is 4, and non-occurances is 7
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 1, i is 1, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 4, belady occurances is 4, and non-occurances is 8
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 0, i is 3, number of faults for three is 12, number of faults for four is 3, belady occurances is 3, and non-occurances is 4
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 1, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 3, belady occurances is 3, and non-occurances is 5
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 2, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 3, belady occurances is 3, and non-occurances is 6
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 3, i is 4, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 3, belady occurances is 3, and non-occurances is 7
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 20, number of faults for three is 7, number of faults for four is 3, belady occurances is 3, and non-occurances is 8
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 5, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 3, belady occurances is 3, and non-occurances is 9
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 2, i is 0, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 3, belady occurances is 3, and non-occurances is 10
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 3, i is 3, number of faults for three is 13, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 1
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 0, number of faults for three is 11, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 2
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 5, i is 0, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 3
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 4, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 4
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 5, i is 20, number of faults for three is 7, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 5
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 6, i is 20, number of faults for three is 7, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 6
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 7, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 7
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 8, i is 20, number of faults for three is 7, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 8
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 9, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 9
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 10, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 0, belady occurances is 0, and non-occurances is 10
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 0, i is 1, number of faults for three is 11, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 11
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 1, i is 0, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 12
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 1, i is 2, number of faults for three is 14, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 2
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 0, i is 0, number of faults for three is 10, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 3
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 1, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 4
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 2, i is 3, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 5
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 3, i is 1, number of faults for three is 9, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 6
Belady's Anomaly did not occur, p is 4, i is 20, number of faults for three is 8, number of faults for four is 1, belady occurances is 1, and non-occurances is 7
```

Apologizes for lack of spacing. The only thing i can think of is I re-declare i in some of the functions I call, but that's local scope so it shouldn't matter.

The code never terminates because p never reaches 1000. Does anyone have any idea what's happening here?

Comment: Accessing `faults[4]` causes undefined behavior

Comment: there's nothing I can tell about whats wrong except what @sunqingyao said.

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Apart from the out of bounds array access already identified you may have other bugs in the functions that are not shown (e.g. `initializeTables`) which are causing Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

How big is arr[] ?

One of the functions (not pasted here) probably writes data outside it boundaries, causing variable p to be overwritten.